# There is a collection of patches for gcc?

Tags: gcc, gnu, patch

The linux kernel project tries to collect all the useful patches in a single place, they are not hard to locate if you need one, with `gcc` I can't locate a resource, online or offline, with the official releases or with the development snapshots, that actually provides patches that can be useful for who wants to rebuild `gcc` from sources .

There is a way I can see a list of all the patches available for `gcc` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it on the official website. Don't know if this could help you rebuild gcc though.
https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/
https://gcc.gnu.org/snapshots.html

Comment: ok, I missed that mailing list but here ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/gcc/snapshots/ I see no patches .